# UILabel on UITableViewCell does not appear correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have an interface configured using constraints in interface builder.  It is set up as shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywyze.jpg.

When the cell is rendered, the right hand label does not appear (but a space for it remains): https://i.stack.imgur.com/p99IC.jpg.

The cell in question is a custom UITableViewCell subclass:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProgressCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailTextLabel;

@end
```

There is no further logic on the class.

The table view cell is instantiated from the identifier that I have set on the storyboard:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProgressCell";
    ProgressCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                         forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Object *room = [self.rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = room.name;
    cell.progressView.progress = 1.0f - ((float)room.avail)/room.total;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", room.avail, room.total];

    return cell;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the end of the function and do `po [[cell detailTextLabel] text]`, the text is set correctly.  The label is not hidden.

I am completely at a loss as to the possible cause.  What could be triggering this behaviour?

Other things I've tried:

- renaming the property to something other than detailTextLabel (in case of a possible clash) does not work
- if I add a third label, with default text, that shows correctly
- if I add a third label and connect that outlet in IB to the one that does not appear, then the default text for the problem label appears, but the third label is hidden

EDIT:

If I log the ultimate position of the frame in question, it sits at `{{0, 44}, {0, 0}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try to find out whats happening:

- Put a red background on the label.
- Do an `NSLog` with the label's frame and your cell's contentView frame.
- Put a hardcoded text on it. `cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Hi";`

Comment: A red background does not show up.  There's no real point logging the frame, unfortunately, as it's still undefined/0,0 (for all views) in the creation method, as the constraints have not yet been applied.  I've already tried hardcoded text, to no avail :/

Comment: add a `-(void)test:(UITableViewCell *)cell` method and do `[self performSelector:@selector(test:) withObject:cell afterDelay:1.0]; on your `cellForRowAtIndex:` and you can do the logging there. The point is to know WHERE the cell is, if it's on the side or if it's where it supposed to be but not visible or something

Comment: You could also try to use custom `UILabels` instead of trying to reuse the existing `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`

Comment: I've tried using different label names, but to no avail (they are custom UILabels, though).  Logging was a good idea, though; it turns out that the UILabel is being rendered with a frame of {{0, 44}, {0, 0}}.  Given that it has a fixed distance from the right hand edge constraint, I don't see why this could happen.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm no expert on `autolayouts`, but perhaps the constraints applied to it make it hold a steady margin to the right and the constraint to your progress view makes it shrink. You could try using `autoresizingMasks` for this simple cell, they're much easier to understand and work with.

Comment: Also, something odd I noticed, the point {0, 44} is actually on the left most side, and just outside of your cell's space. Pretty weird if you ask me ... but beats me without being able to test it myself

Comment: Yeah, it's quite weird that it's showing up on the other side of the view.  I've never had this problem with autolayout before.  I want to set this up visually in IB (if I didn't care about that, I'd just generate the frames myself), so autoresizingMasks are a no go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the constraints of the storyboard auto layout.Check the label constraint such that it is visible when the cell is resized in the tableview

Comment: The constraints are shown in the first link, and look ok to me.  Do you see anything wrong with them?

Comment: can you make all the elements background color clearcolor and the detailed text some other color and check it is shown anywhere?

Comment: It turns out that it's being shown at {{0, 44}, {0, 0}}, of all places

Comment: Yes, but how is that possible with a priority 1000 constraint locking it to the far right, and a priority 1000 constraint setting its width?

Comment: I suggest disabling auto layout